# getting all possibilities from 2 matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to get all possible outcome from 2 different dimension matrix.
 say,

```
A=[1 2 3 4;2 3 4 5]
```

and

```
B=[11 12; 13 14; 15 16]
```

with the output of

```
C=[1 2 3 4 11 12; 1 2 3 4 13 14; 1 2 3 4 15 16; 2 3 4 5 11 12; 2 3 4 5 13 14; 2 3 4 5 15 16]
```

I have tried using for loop method but I find it very inefficient and would therefore like to have a better approach to it. 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by all possible outcome? What is the operation you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Don't want to use for loop. Just run these 
>> C(1,:) = [A(1,:),B(1,:)];
>> C(2,:) = [A(1,:),B(2,:)];
>> C(3,:) = [A(1,:),B(3,:)];
>> C(4,:) = [A(2,:),B(1,:)];
>> C(5,:) = [A(2,:),B(2,:)];
>> C(6,:) = [A(2,:),B(3,:)];

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply,like the example showed in the question.  . assuming rows are individual. by using the example above, assume A=[M; N] and B=[X; Y; Z] with the outcome of C=[ M X; M Y; M Z; N X; N Y; N Z]. sorry for the confusing explanation I'm not good at explaining it.

Comment: I cant type it row by row because in the program im writing matrix A has 3 million rows in it.

Answer (score 1):

If the repetition of matrix A is always a the number of rows of matrix B and repetition of matrix B is always the number of rows of A. Then, you can use the functions `kron` and `repmat` to achieve what you wanted. So, in this example, C can be obtained with a single line as

```
[kron(A, ones(size(B, 1), 1)) repmat(B, [size(A, 1) 1])]
```

Comment: HOLY SHIIIIIIT!!!! damn you are good. that work so well cut down the run time soooo much. thanks a bunch!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexing to achieve this by

```
C=[A(repmat(1:size(A,1), 1, size(B,1)), :) B(repmat(1:size(B,1), 1, size(A,1)), :)];
```

A more readable version is

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(1:size(A,1), 1:size(B,1)); 
C=[A(X(:),:) B(Y(:),:)];
```